# Google Keyword planner says 'keywords don't have any searches'

Tags: seo, google-keyword-tool

I am working on an SEO optimized page for a certain main keyword consist of 4-5 keywords. When I search on Google, it returns 20K results. On Google Key planner it says no search was found against result. Who should I believe?

Answer (score 2):

When you use the keyword planner it estimates how many people search each month on average; if it is very few it will say zero so there may be a few searches, but a very small number. On the Google Search results it shows the number of webpages that match rather than the number of people searching. Typically searches are two to three word long, it could be worth looking at shorter tail keywords that could be derived from your longer keyword.

Comment: Alright but sounds weird. Search for *PHP Developers* or *Rails Developers* or even *Python Developers* and results come less than 50. Hard to digest people are not looking for developers

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, you're targeting setting is right. For this, I target All location with English language.

I am getting this result for PHP developer (9,900 monthly search), PHP programming (8100), PHP developers(1300), PHP development(1900) and so on.

Here Php Developer and PHP developers both are different, but PHP Developer is total of Hire PHP developer, Best PHP developer, Local PHP Developer and so on.

**If you already know about your keywords variants, then Group ideas gives you tons of keywords ideas.**

For specific keywords, you need to ON show adult ideas from Keyword option (Left Side Panel).